# Amazon GetSessionToken throws : A WebException with status TrustFailure was thrown

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using amazon web apis to generate federated user credentials e.g. GetSessionToken. It's working fine on my localhost machine but throw error on live server . Any guesses?

Error throws:
A WebException with status TrustFailure was thrown.

Comment: I got this error when I opened fiddler2 and it was gone when I closed fiddler again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not sound like an AWS exception. It sounds like an SSL/TLS issue related to certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - is your date correct on your machine?

The AWS connection process will throw out the request if the date is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036741/a-webexception-with-status-trustfailure-was-thrown-amazons3-net-3-5-version-3/39729192#39729192) . In my case, the server I was receiving the error on did not have the correct cert in its trusted root certificate authorities. Adding the correct cert resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check certificate settings installed on Production machine