# A WebException with status TrustFailure was thrown. AmazonS3 .net 3.5 Version 3 invoking from sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, sharepoint-2010, aws-sdk

Currently I am working in POC with CRUD operations using AmazonS3 Sdk for .net 3.5 version 3. I am trying to retrieve the Region Endpoint(Location) of the specific bucket name using secret key and Access Key and bucket name( has Location: EU (Frankfurt) (eu-central-1)). in order to establish connection 
with AmazonS3 and perform CRUD operations
So I get the  A WebException with status TrustFailure was thrown when I tried to get the Region Endpoint from share point(web page I create my own page using the master page of SharePoint) in order to create AmazonS3Client instance with Region Retrieve.
with the following code:

```
private string defaultAmazonHttpsHost = "https://s3.amazonaws.com";
private string defaultAmazonHttpHost = "http://s3.amazonaws.com"; 

private Amazon.RegionEndpoint GetRegionEndpoint(string bucket, BasicAWSCredentials amazonCredentials, bool useSSL)
{
    Amazon.RegionEndpoint regiongEndpoint = null;
    AmazonS3Config configurationClient = new AmazonS3Config();
    configurationClient.UseHttp = !useSSL;
    configurationClient.ServiceURL = useSSL ? defaultAmazonHttpsHost : defaultAmazonHttpHost;
    try
    {
        using (AmazonS3Client clientConnection = new AmazonS3Client(amazonCredentials, configurationClient))
        {
            GetBucketLocationRequest locationRequest = new GetBucketLocationRequest();
            locationRequest.BucketName = bucket;
            string locationName = clientConnection.GetBucketLocation(locationRequest).Location.Value;
            if (locationName.Equals("EU", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                regiongEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationName))
            {
                regiongEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
            }
            else
            {
                regiongEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(locationName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
          throw amazonS3Exception;
    }
    catch (Exception unExpectedException)
    {
        throw unExpectedException;
    }
    return regiongEndpoint;
}
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("my access Key", "my secret key");
AmazonS3Config configurationAmazon = new AmazonS3Config();
configurationAmazon.RegionEndpoint = GetRegionEndpoint("bucketName", credentials, false);
 AmazonS3Client _s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, configurationAmazon );
```

My task Perform CRUD operations + test connection with AmazonS3 Sdk .net 3.5 version 3 , with the source  information :
-secret key
- access key
- bucket Name

the  strange is if this part code run(execute) since another Project (without share point interaction for example: Console Project) I do not get this exception) Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following before execute any request to amazonS3 and now it works as expected I think the problem was with the certificates that sharepoint is using .

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=   
delegate(  
    object sender,   
    X509Certificate certificate,   
    X509Chain chain,   
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)  
    {  
         return true;  
    };
```

the [post](http://dobrzanski.net/2009/04/01/systemnetwebexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel/) provide a explanation about it

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is "TrustFailure". There's something wrong with the certificate.  In my case, this error was caused because my company uses Websense, a web filter/security suite that intercepts and reissues https certificates for web traffic so it can spy on you. Even if you don't use anything like that, the bottom line is that your computer doesn't trust the issuer of the certificate being used by the remote computer. The server on which I was receiving this error did not have the correct certificate in its Trusted Root Certification Authorities. After importing the correct trusted root cert ([Add trusted root certificate authority to local computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841(v=ws.11).aspx)), I no longer received the error.

If you don't think this is the case, you can get more details on what the exception is by either writing the details to console or putting a breakpoint on the Console.WriteLine here and actually inspect the certificate and ssl errors:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;

.....
.....
//before you make the request
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
delegate (
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + certificate.Subject + ", Issuer: " + certificate.Issuer + ". SSL Errors: " + sslPolicyErrors.ToString());
    return false;
};
```

The key point here is that you need to find the certificate issue and resolve it instead of leaving yourself vulnerable by ignoring all ssl errors.

Answer (score 0):

TrustFailure can also be caused by the date being incorrect on the machine.